# How to use old password for FE_user when I updating a profile in fe_manager?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.31 and fe_manager 5.5.3.

I need to achieve a goal when I can edit FE user fields, e.g. name, surname, phone, etc, but I need to leave old FE user password untouchable - use the current password for this user in case when user don't want to change a password specially.

For now I need to fill two passwords fields in edit form, because then I leave them empty I can't submit a form and save updated data.

I can't find this option in fe_manager - maybe I lost something settings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe, mass editing would be a workaround. This way, you can select the fields to be changed: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-editors/main/en-us/ListModule/MassEditing/Index.html